# Move array's one element to the end position and another one to the front position, and the others should be in the remaining position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Array: ['B', 'D', 'I', 'M', 'Other', 'T', 'U'].

I want to sort it in order: ['T', 'B', 'D', 'I', 'M', 'U', 'Other'].

How can I implement it with JavaScript?

Comment: What is your sorting criteria?

Comment: There are no criteria. Just move the letter T to the beginning of the array and the word "other" to the end of the array.

Comment: Sounds like criteria to me... lol

Comment: Did you attempt anything with a custom sort function?

Comment: I tried this piece of code, but it didn't work: `sort((x) => x ==='T'? -1  : x === 'Other' ? 1 : 0 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an object with the order and sort the array.

```js
const
    array = ['B', 'D', 'I', 'M', 'Other', 'T', 'U'],
    order = { T: -1, Other: Number.MAX_VALUE };

array.sort((a, b) => (order[a] || 0) - (order[b] || 0));

console.log(...array);
```

Comment: Yes I wanted to do exactly this one. Thank you!

Comment: great! maybe the lage number is to large, one is working as well.

Comment: This is a very clever answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do you simply want this one, exact array to have two values moved elsewhere within the array? If so, you can do this, assuming your original array is called `arr`:

```
let startSplice = arr.splice(5,1)
let endSplice = arr.splice(4,1)

arr.unshift(startSplice[0])
arr.push(endSplice[0])
```

But I wouldn't really call this "sorting". Sorting in an array context typically implies that you have set rules on what you want the array order to be, for every element in the array, and that you may encounter various arrays that need to be sorted with these rules.

If your rules are simply "If I encounter a 'T', put it at the beginning of the array", and "if I encounter 'Other', put it at the end", then you could do this:

```
arr.sort((a,b) => {
    if (a === 'Other') {
        return 1
    } else if (a === 'T') {
        return -1
    } else if (b === 'Other') {
        return -1
    } else if (b === 'T') {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
})
```

Comment: Array contains strings. I edit the question, thank you.